# Get list of parameters from method decorator in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

In a typescript project, there are about 2000+ methods/events that are triggered under different scenarios. I want to enforce that an additional parameter 'executionTime' should be added to some of the events. If that parameter is missing, a message should be logged to console. For this, I have implemented method decorator, however, I have to rely on regex to check for parameter name from the method body. Is there a direct method by which I can get a list of method parameters in the decorator function. Please see below code:

```
class Events {
  name: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.name = message;
  }
 
 @performanceMetrics()
  firstEvent(correlationId: string, executionTime: number): void {
            
    }

    //..........many other events
}

function performanceMetrics() {    
  return function (target: object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    let methodBody:string = descriptor.value;   
    //Here, descriptor.value provides the entire method body, so regex has to be used.
    //Is there a direct way to get list of parameters of method 'firstEvent'?
    const regex = new RegExp(".+( executionTime).*{");      
    if(!regex.test(methodBody))
    {
        console.log("executionTime parameter is missing.");
    } 
  };
}

new Events("Test").firstEvent("s1", 10);
```

Comment: No, you cannot do this in any other way. You cannot access arguments' names in any way except calling `function.toString()`. And if you try to use types for this, firstly you cannot enforce the name of the argument, only its type. Secondly you cannot force the function to actually use this argument, the function can always simply ignore it and types won't complain. The only thing I can think of is a custom eslint rule, I don't think there is a better way than what you are already doing using only typescript and javascript